# How to share webpage on Line Messanger?

Tags: php, html

I have below code

```
<a href="https://access.line.me/oauth2/v2.1/login?returnUri=%2Foauth2%2Fv2.1%2Fauthorize%2Fconsent%3Fscope%3Dopenid%2Bprofile%2Bfriends%2Bgroups%2Btimeline.post%2Bmessage.write%26response_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fsocial-plugins.line.me%252Fwidget%252FloginCallback%253FreturnUrl%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fsocial-plugins.line.me%25252Fwidget%25252Fclose%26state%3Da5d22cad15b2246308e149f69c82a7%26client_id%3D1446101138&loginChannelId=1446101138">Link</a>
```

What is the correct parameter which is mandatory & needs to pass?

This is encoded string. How to pass with PHP or HTML

Or we need to use

https://social-plugins.line.me/en/how_to_install#likebutton

Comment: You want to print this url with PHP or what? Your question is not good at all.

Comment: What are the parameters need to pass

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are requesting exactly, but using [PHP urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php), you can see that in this URL there is 6 parameters : `returnUri, response_type, redirect_uri, state, client_id, loginChannelId`.

You can start with `urldecode(url)`. This [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/78f4af09528e42da6da3a3de57e2fbe4aedf2f21) example might help you. Good luck!

Comment: Yes exactly this. With sample example

Comment: @AnkitShah, check the example.